# what is the best way to combine different JAVA classes in one single class?

Tags: java, list, dictionary

I have 3 different JAVA classes named as A, B, C . All these classes contain either each other's reference object or a list of objects. My main aim is to combine all these classes into one single JAVA class (A). Please find below the structure:

```
public class A {

    private B b;
    ...

}

public class B {
    private List<C> c;
    ...

}

public class C{
    private TreeMap<int, int> t;
    ...
}
```

Since I am new to JAVA , I am not sure how would I combine these together into one single class 'A'? Experts please help me in this case.

Comment: I think in this case being a bit less generic than what you've written might help. What do A, B and C represent in your program and what are the list/trees/references for?

Comment: Also, why do you want to?

Comment: Having 3 separate classes look good enough. Why do you need to combine them?

Comment: I was just trying to do simple exercises with JAVA collections and finding out the best practices for the same. This problem seems to be list of maps  but I want to know whether that is the most optimized way of doing it or not?

Comment: In OO paradigm what's really more important is what the objects represent, but using a list of maps is a fair idea for the implementation. You might want to provide a proper interface for accessing it, though, since you had a reason for having the three tightly-bound classes to start with. As to optimization I don't think there's any obviously better way of doing it.

Comment: I think what you're asking about here is 'Java Polymorphism', you should read about that elsewhere. But to answer your question, you make C extend B, and have B contain an instance of A, and expose A's methods as 'delegate' methods.

Comment: @Richard - I disagree, making C extend B would admit that C is in fact a kind of B, which is not what the author shows.

Comment: I took 'combine all these classes into one single JAVA class' to mean 'polymorphism'. But what this person might need to know about is 'inner classes'? Is that what you're suggesting?

Comment: No Richard, I don't mean to use polymorphism. These is a HAS relationship classes. I think what lared says is right . I will try that thing now.

Comment: WHY do YOU put JAVA in ALL caps WHEN Java IS not AN acronym?

Comment: @AbhishekPidwa - Yup, I basically meant that there's composition and aggregation there, not `is-a` relationship.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the class combined [single Java class (A)]:

```
public class A {
    private A b;
    private List<A> c;
    private TreeMap<Integer, Integer> t
    ...
}
```

Now, for a little OOP best practices rant. You need to think of each class as having a single responsibility ([single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)). If you say, "this class does this **and** that". Then it has too many responsibilities. The key word is "and". It implies multiple responsibilities. If you can safely say, each one of these classes share a single responsibility, then I guess it's okay to join them together. However, I'm doubting this is the case. It seems to make more since to keep them split.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your code will not compile, we don't use `TreeMap<int, int>`, colections only use Objects, it's [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html):

> A collection represents a group of objects, known as its elements.

Otherwise. your code seems to be good enough, regarding your comment:

> simple exercises with JAVA collections and finding out the best
>   practices for the same. This problem seems to be list of maps but I
>   want to know whether that is the most optimized way of doing it or
>   not?

your question has nothing to do with optimized use of collections, but if you are not willing to use `class B` and `class C` in other classes, then you can use `inner classes` like this:

```
class A {

   private B b;

   class B {
       private List<C> c;
       ....
    }
    class C {
       private TreeMap<Integer, Integer> t;
       ....
    }
}
```

More informations about how use inner classes, could be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html).